# 'comment_popup_link()' with different #ID on Genesis Framework

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, reply, genesis

I want to add a "comment" and "reply" links under every post on my Wordpress theme. Standard "comment_popup_link()" function creates such link:

```
http://website.com/page/#comments
```

What I want is to create another one, next to the above, looking like this:

```
http://website.com/page/#reply
```

How can I do that?

I'm trying to add it on Wordpress theme with Genesis Framework. There's a shortcode available - [post_comments] that does the same thing as 'comment_popup_link()'. The output of above shortcode/function is shown in first code example.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Can you give us a little more details ?

Comment: I'm not sure what more details could I provide. I'm trying to add it on Wordpress theme with Genesis Framework. There's a shortcode available  - [post_comments] that does the same thing as 'comment_popup_link()'. 

The output of above shortcode/function is shown in first code example. I'm trying to achieve the second example as well.

Comment: I dont think I can help you with this since Im not much in to Genesis Framework. How ever, I have edited your question and tagged it properly so as to attract people who handles Genesis templates.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if it's just Genesis Framework question, or is it based purely on Wordpress. The 'comment_popup_link()' function i standard in WP.


Now I also spotted I made a mistake in title and first sentence, providing probably wrong function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty and fast solution would be something like this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#reply">
    <?php comments_number('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: You are a gem! Here's modified version of what I need exactly:   
   
`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#respond">Reply</a>`   
   
Unfortunately I can't vote yet, but your answer is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking the [Checkmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark) beside it. Thank you:=)